# Calculate difference between min and max for each column only if higher then 0

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I need to calculate the difference between odds based on the value in the 'updated' column at the moment I take odds where the updated value is a min and minus it from odds where the updated value is max. It works perfect but I've just realized that in some columns happens to be 0 sometimes and I was wondering if it's possible to select the minimum still based on the updated column and only values where higher than 0.

That's how the table looks like

| fixture_id | H_odds | D_odds | A_odds | ev_tstamp | updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120000 | 1.40 | 1.50 | 1.30 | 132000 | 12 |
| 120000 | 1.10 | 1.10 | 1.10 | 132000 | 11 |
| 120000 | 1.20 | 0 | 1.60 | 132000 | 10 |

And that's what I would like to get back

| fixture_id | H_odds | D_odds | A_odds | ev_tstamp | updated | dif_h | dif_d | dif_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120000 | 1.40 | 1.50 | 1.30 | 132000 | 12 | 0.2 | 0.4 | -0.3 |

That's what I'm getting back at the moment

| fixture_id | H_odds | D_odds | A_odds | ev_tstamp | updated | dif_h | dif_d | dif_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120000 | 1.40 | 1.50 | 1.30 | 132000 | 12 | 0.2 | **1.5** | -0.3 |

The code I'm using

```
select
   t_max.*,
   (t_max.H_odds - t_min.H_odds) as dif_h,
   (t_max.D_odds - t_min.D_odds) as dif_d,
   (t_max.A_odds - t_min.A_odds) as dif_a
from
(
   select
      fixture_id,
      min(updated) min_updated,
      max(updated) max_updated
  from
      test
  group by
      fixture_id
) as t1
join test as t_min on (t_min.fixture_id = t1.fixture_id and t_min.updated = t1.min_updated)
join test as t_max on (t_max.fixture_id = t1.fixture_id and t_max.updated = t1.max_updated)
```

Comment: `MIN(CASE WHEN D_odds > 0 THEN updated END)`. If a value in the row is `0` then it will be ignored by MIN().

Comment: So you want the latest odds, and the difference between the latest odds and the earliest odds for the same fixture and outcome?

Comment: Yes, and I want the 0 odds to be skipped when calculating difference so   each odds column has to be treat separately as mention in the answer bellow. You can see what mean if you'll at the table column dif_d in the example above

Answer (score 0):

This solution only works on MySQL 8+.

I would suggest window functions.  The following treats each odds column separately . . . and it does not make any assumptions about the odds increasing or decreasing with each update:

```
select fixture_id, ev_tstamp, max(updated),
       max(case when update = max_h_update then h_odds end) as max_h,
       max(case when update = max_d_update then h_odds end) as max_d,
       max(case when update = max_a_update then h_odds end) as max_a,
       (max(case when update = max_h_update then h_odds end) -
        max(case when update = min_h_update then h_odds end)
       ) as h_diff,
       (max(case when update = max_d_update then d_odds end) -
        max(case when update = min_d_update then d_odds end)
       ) as d_diff,
       (max(case when update = max_a_update then a_odds end) -
        max(case when update = min_a_update then a_odds end)
       ) as a_diff
from (select t.*,
             max(case when h_odds <> 0 then update end) over (partition by fixture_id) as max_h_update,
             min(case when h_odds <> 0 then update end) over (partition by fixture_id) as min_h_update,
             max(case when d_odds <> 0 then update end) over (partition by fixture_id) as max_h_update,
             min(case when d_odds <> 0 then update end) over (partition by fixture_id) as min_h_update,
             max(case when a_odds <> 0 then update end) over (partition by fixture_id) as max_a_update,
             min(case when a_odds <> 0 then update end) over (partition by fixture_id) as min_a_update
      from test t
     ) t
group by fixture_id, ev_tstamp;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using mysql 5.7 will partition by work on it?

Comment: I've just tried it and I got error  ".......right syntax to use near '(partition by...."

Comment: Window functions are a poor substitute for (fixing) poor schema design

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(fixture_id INT NOT NULL
,updated INT NOT NULL
,outcome ENUM('Home win','Draw','Away win') NOT NULL
,odds DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(fixture_id,outcome,updated)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(120,12,'Home win',1.40),
(120,11,'Home win',1.10),
(120,10,'Home win',1.20),
(120,12,'Draw',1.50),
(120,11,'Draw',1.10),
(120,12,'Away win',1.30),
(120,11,'Away win',1.10),
(120,10,'Away win',1.60);
```

Latest odds:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT fixture_id
            , outcome
            , MAX(updated) min_updated
         FROM my_table x
        GROUP 
           BY fixture_id
            , outcome
     ) y
    ON y.fixture_id = x.fixture_id
   AND y.outcome = x.outcome
   AND y.min_updated = x.updated;
   Earliest odds:
```

Earliest odds:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT fixture_id
            , outcome
            , MIN(updated) min_updated
         FROM my_table x
        GROUP 
           BY fixture_id
            , outcome
     ) y
    ON y.fixture_id = x.fixture_id
   AND y.outcome = x.outcome
   AND y.min_updated = x.updated;
```

Delta:

```
SELECT a.*
     , a.odds - b.odds delta
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT fixture_id
                   , outcome
                   , MAX(updated) min_updated
                FROM my_table x
               GROUP 
                  BY fixture_id
                   , outcome
            ) y
           ON y.fixture_id = x.fixture_id
          AND y.outcome = x.outcome
          AND y.min_updated = x.updated
     ) a
 JOIN
    ( SELECT x.*
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT fixture_id
                   , outcome
                   , MIN(updated) min_updated
                FROM my_table x
               GROUP 
                  BY fixture_id
                   , outcome
            ) y
           ON y.fixture_id = x.fixture_id
          AND y.outcome = x.outcome
          AND y.min_updated = x.updated
    ) b
   ON b.fixture_id = a.fixture_id
  AND b.outcome = a.outcome;
```

Result:

```
    +------------+---------+----------+------+-------+
    | fixture_id | updated | outcome  | odds | delta |
    +------------+---------+----------+------+-------+
    |        120 |      12 | Home win | 1.40 |  0.20 |
    |        120 |      12 | Draw     | 1.50 |  0.40 |
    |        120 |      12 | Away win | 1.30 | -0.30 |
    +------------+---------+----------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank for the input but the table structure is different, each table record contains odds for all the markets

Comment: I strongly suggest you amend the structure.

Comment: I would do... just the thing is there is like another 20 columns for other markets so is more convenient to keep it the way it is

Comment: On the contrary, it's vastly more convenient and efficient to revise the design. What if you suddenly have 21 markets? You then have to revise all structure and all queries. With a normalised design, the query for 20 markets or 21 markets is exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right here, I'll look into it

Comment: Do you think this query it's too complex when performed on too many records? I just tried on a table with around 70 000 records and it gives me time out error

Comment: It can be written more efficiently. I wrote it this way so you could see the logic behind its construction. But even so, on a well indexed dat set of that size, it should be ok. We can look at re-writing it but, as others have mentioned, upgrading to 8.0+ would simplify this task.

Comment: I did Indexed the column fixture_id, outcome, updated but it gives me time out error anyway. I would upgrade to 8.0 but I'm on the share server and that's not an option

Comment: Fixture_id is the first column in the Primary key, so I don't think there's any point is indexing it separately. Post the EXPLAIN for the above, and I'll have a think about re-writing the query tomorrow.

Comment: I'm just not sure if I meant to post it as another answer or update the original one since the original question is not longer an issue....

Comment: I've created a new question so it's more readable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491610/finding-difference-between-values-base-on-min-and-max-on-another-column-for-each

Answer (score 0):

I just modify the code little bit to calculate the difference only for specific group of odds (avg) so it look like bellow. It worked just once though, it took over 15 seconds to process and the other times I tried it didn't work due to time out error.  Just to clarify in my structure the market column is the 'outcome' column from your example.

```
explain SELECT a.*
    , a.odds - b.odds delta
FROM 
 ( SELECT x.*
     FROM average_odds x
     JOIN
        ( SELECT fix_id
               , market
               , MAX(updated) min_updated
            FROM average_odds x where odds_type=avg
           GROUP BY fix_id
               , market
        ) y
       ON y.fix_id = x.fix_id
      AND y.market = x.market
      AND y.min_updated = x.updated
 ) a
JOIN
( SELECT x.*
     FROM average_odds x
     JOIN
        ( SELECT fix_id
               , market
               , MIN(updated) min_updated
            FROM average_odds x where odds_type=avg
           GROUP BY fix_id
               , market
        ) y
       ON y.fix_id = x.fix_id
      AND y.market = x.market
      AND y.min_updated = x.updated
) b
 ON b.fix_id = a.fix_id
AND b.market = a.market  
ORDER BY `delta` ASC
```

That's the explain table

| ID | S TYPE | table.. | parti | type | pos_keys | KEY | key len | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived3> | null | all | null | null | null | null | 17466 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | x | null | ref | fix,fixi,market,updat | fix | 4 | y.fix_id | 596 | 0.11 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | x | null | ref | fix,fixi,market,updat | fix | 4 | y.fix_id | 596 | 2.27 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived5> | null | ref | auto_key0> | auto_key0> | 31 | y.fix_id,y.market,bobi.x.updated | 10 | 100.00 | using index |
| 5 | DERIVED | x | null | ref | boki | boki | 4 | const | 17466 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using file... |
| 3 | DERIVED | x | null | ref | boki | boki | 4 | const | 17466 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using file... |