# Slow query: find difference between values base on min and max on another column for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions, mysql-5.7

With reference to [Calculate difference between min and max for each column only if higher then 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455931/calculate-difference-between-min-and-max-for-each-column-only-if-higher-then-0/66458066?noredirect=1#comment117546141_66458066..).

I'm looking for a difference in odds where MIN and MAX in updated column for each same fix_id for selected odds_type. With the output I would like to get back other rows where value in updated column was max.  That's how my table looks like

| fix_id | odds | market | updated | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 1.80 | home | **160** | avg |
| 120 | 1.40 | home | 150 | avg |
| 120 | 2.00 | home | **110** | avg |
| 188 | 1.00 | u/o | 200 | REG |
| 121 | 1.60 | away | **160** | avg |
| 121 | 1.40 | away | 150 | avg |
| 121 | 1.10 | away | **110** | avg |

What I'm expecting to get

| fix_id | odds | market | updated | diff | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 1.80 | home | 160 | -0.2 | avg |
| 121 | 1.60 | away | 160 | 0.5 | avg |

The code I'm using is working but it takes too much time to process and with more data I get time out error

```
  SELECT a.*
, a.odds - b.odds delta
FROM 
( SELECT x.*
 FROM average_odds x
 JOIN
    ( SELECT fix_id
           , market
           , MAX(updated) min_updated
        FROM average_odds x where type='avg'
       GROUP BY fix_id
           , market
    ) y
   ON y.fix_id = x.fix_id
  AND y.market = x.market
  AND y.min_updated = x.updated
) a
JOIN
( SELECT x.*
 FROM average_odds x
 JOIN
    ( SELECT fix_id
           , market
           , MIN(updated) min_updated
        FROM average_odds x where  type='avg'
       GROUP BY fix_id
           , market
    ) y
   ON y.fix_id = x.fix_id
  AND y.market = x.market
  AND y.min_updated = x.updated
) b
ON b.fix_id = a.fix_id
AND b.market = a.market  
ORDER BY `delta` ASC
```

Here is also explain table from sql for the query that took 15 seconds

| ID | S TYPE | table.. | parti | type | pos_keys | KEY | key len | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived3> | null | all | null | null | null | null | 17466 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | x | null | ref | fix,fixi,market,updat | fix | 4 | y.fix_id | 596 | 0.11 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | x | null | ref | fix,fixi,market,updat | fix | 4 | y.fix_id | 596 | 2.27 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived5> | null | ref | auto_key0> | auto_key0> | 31 | y.fix_id,y.market,bobi.x.updated | 10 | 100.00 | using index |
| 5 | DERIVED | x | null | ref | boki | boki | 4 | const | 17466 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using file... |
| 3 | DERIVED | x | null | ref | boki | boki | 4 | const | 17466 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using file... |

there is a table defition

| Field | TYPE | NULL | key | default | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fix_id | int(20) | no | MUL | NULL |  |
| market | varchar(20) | no | MUL | NULL |  |
| label | varchar(20) | no |  | NULL |  |
| odds | decimal(4,2) | no |  | NULL |  |
| updated | int(20) | no | MUL | NULL |  |
| ev_tstamp | int(20) | no |  | NULL |  |
| TYPE | varchar(20) | no | MUL | NULL |  |
| market_id | int(20) | no |  | NULL |  |

At the moment the query takes 15s to perform on around 75 000 rows  but most of the time I get time out error. I need to use it on table with 500 000 rows and I wonder if that's possible. P.S I'm using MySQL 5.7.29 and I'm on the share server so I'm not able to upgrade it to 8

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7 and I'm on the share server so I'm not able to upgrade it to 8

php

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then please [edit] your question to give us more information.

Comment: Done, I've edited my question and added table definition and exact MySQL version

Comment: Just curious; Why is your table different from mine?

Comment: I've just added couple extra columns if that's what you mean...

Comment: No. You're missing the PK (and you changed the data types). Incidentally the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless, and best omitted. If INT(20) was  thing, then you could probably individually label every drop of water in our oceans using that data type.

Comment: Also, I find SHOW CREATE TABLE much more useful than DESCRIBE.

Comment: Shall I add an unique column to the table ?

Comment: If you like; it won't help though!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit confuse already.Do you think there anything I can change with the table structure that would speed up this query?

Comment: Shouldn't the data say `1.60` instead of `160`?  If that needs fixing please check the rest of the data and Question for typos.

Comment: Are you referring to updated column in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the difference between the two most recent rows for each `fix_id` where `type = 'avg'`.

If so, I would suggest variables and conditional aggregation:

```
select fix_id,
       max(case when rn = 1 then odds end) as odds,
       max(case when rn = 1 then market end) as market,
       max(case when rn = 1 then away end) as away,
       sum(case when rn = 1 then odds when rn = 2 then - odds end) as diff,
       max(type) as type
from (select ao.*,
             (@rn := if(@f = fix_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@fn := fix_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select ao.*
            from average_odds ao
            where type = 'avg'
            order by ao.fix_id, ao.updated desc
           ) ao cross join
           (select @f := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) ao
where rn <= 2
group by fix_id;
```

Comment: I would like to get  a difference in odds between minimum and maximum on updated column for each fix_id not for two most recent rows

Comment: I add bold on the updated column  for the values I need to select

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to filter the table and a correlated subquery to get the `odds` for the earliest `update`:

```
SELECT a.*,
       a.odds - (SELECT t.odds FROM average_odds t WHERE t.fix_id = a.fix_id ORDER BY t.updated LIMIT 1) diff
FROM average_odds a
WHERE type = 'avg'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM average_odds t WHERE t.fix_id = a.fix_id AND t.updated > a.updated)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=71777e43a3ea3364b8f525534ea673b5).
Results:

| fix_id | odds | market | updated | type | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 1.80 | home | 160 | avg | -0.20 |
| 121 | 1.60 | away | 160 | avg | 0.50 |

Comment: It gives me timeout error too. I think I should mention that the 'updated' values are different for each fix_id

Comment: @user2741313 Do you have any indexes? An index on (fix_id, updated) would help.

Comment: I have an index on fix_id, market, updated, type

Comment: I just realize I get the diff wrong with this code...

Comment: @user2741313 with which code? Your expected results are identical with the results of my query.

Comment: When I try the code you wrote in the answer it returns random number in diff column. I've just added after  "type = 'avg' "   "and fix_id=17695422" to check and returns diff -1.4. In the table there are only two rows with fix_id 17695422  in one odds are 1.93 and the other one 1.95 so the diff should be 0.02

Comment: *I've just added after "type = 'avg' " "and fix_id=17695422"* so you get wrong results with your code, not mine, because I do not have `....and fix_id=17695422"` in my code. You can see in the demo link that the code works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I've checked the demo an it does work properly, I don't why it returned wrong value in my table when I added a fix_id....

Comment: @user2741313 check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cad2e1a1444d67fe060f76b0e6eeae94 also if you want results for a specific fix_id. It returns the correct value.